# How to make images as hyperlink in windows phone 7?

Tags: .net, windows, windows-phone-7

How to make hyperlink images in windows phone?

Comment: not good enough to upvote but not bad either to downvote....look at him he is surely a fresher, so thats fine to have a question like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, but the favourite seems to be listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197022/wp7-silverlight-hyperlink-image) which suggests using something like the following XAML

```
<HyperlinkButton Height="310" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="206,202,0,0" Name="hyperlinkButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" >
    <HyperlinkButton.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="SplashScreenImage.jpg"/>
    </HyperlinkButton.Background>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct , but I follow a different path.

add an image and in the xaml or by actually accessing it's properties set the tapped event to navigate to the desired page