# Wrap An Image With HyperlinkButton In C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, hyperlink

I can create a textual c# hyperlink...

```
HyperlinkButton sunday_title = new HyperlinkButton();
sunday_title.Content = "Sunday (" + sunday.ToUpper() + ")";
sunday_title.Click += sunday_link_Click;
```

But how do I create a graphical hyperlink?  My first inclination was to use the image as a child, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Here is the c# code to create the graphic...

```
Image sunday_image = new Image();
sunday_image.Source = background_flcb;
Border sunday_border = new Border();
sunday_border.Child = sunday_image;
```

Ultimately, I want to make a whole `grid` a link (but I don't think that's possible).  At the moment, though, I would be happy enough just making the image a link.

[Similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197022/wp7-silverlight-hyperlink-image) have been addressed, but most answers are with XAML.  I'm wanting to do it with c#.

If it makes a difference, this is for a Windows 8 app (although the same logic should apply to a Windows Phone app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most case XAML can easily convert to C# code. For example, this XAML solution from *Similar questions* link above (simplified) :

```
<HyperlinkButton>
    <HyperlinkButton.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="SplashScreenImage.jpg"/>
    </HyperlinkButton.Background>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

is equivalent to following C# code :

```
var hyperlinkButton = new HyperlinkButton();
hyperlinkButton.Background = new ImageBrush{ImageSource = background_flcb};
```

[Other suggested approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4197183/2998271) from the same link, is to simply use `Image` control and handle it's Click/Tap event to navigate to link destination :

```
Image sunday_image = new Image();
sunday_image.Source = background_flcb;
Border sunday_border = new Border();
sunday_border.Child = sunday_image;
sunday_image.Tapped += sunday_image_tapped;
```

Anyway, I don't know whether those approaches will work in Windows 8 as well. Just give it a try. Good Luck.

Comment: You can't do `sunday_image.Click` in Windows 8, apparently (not in the list that Visual Studio gives.

Comment: Pasting your `new ImageBrush` code produces this error... `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Uri' to 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'`

Comment: Try to change new Uri(...) to background_flcb as you used in the question. Apparently ImageSource in win 8 has different parameter

Comment: And about the click event, google search result suggest to try tapped event instead of click for Image in win8

Comment: `Tapped` did the trick.  It allowed me to run a method when `Click` wasn't allowed.  har07, adjusting your second code chuck to `Tapped` would be nice, for future reference.

Comment: Done. Fill free to edit my answer if it still doesn't reflect the exact solution that worked for you.

Comment: Thanks...I didn't realize that I could (or that it was kosher) for me to edit someone else's posts (I figured that was more of a moderator thing).  That's not the exact code that I used (actually, I was able to do `Tapped` on the whole `Grid`, which was my overall goal), but your code does appropriately answer the actual question.